# Python Setter throws Type Error. What is wrong here?

Tags: python, properties, setter

I have a dataclass with an attribute 'open' of type float.
I added a property setter which shall throw a ValueError in case it gets set to a negative value:

```
@open.setter
def open(self, value: float) -> None:
    if value < 0.0:
        raise ValueError("Open value must be positive.")
    self.open = value
```

The error I am getting is:

```
File "<string>", line 4, in __init__
  File "/home/PATH/file.py", line 29, in open
    if value < 0.0:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^
  TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'property' and 'float'
```

I don't really get what I am doing wrong here.
Thanks for any advice!

Comment: "_Open value must be positive._" This is just wrong. You intended that `value` must be non-negative.

Comment: `self.open = value` would be a recursive call to the setter.

Answer (score 1):

The OP was not a
[MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

The code below is.
And it demonstrates a solution to the problem.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._open: float = 2.718

    @property
    def open(self) -> float:
        return self._open

    @open.setter
    def open(self, value: float) -> None:
        if value < 0.0:
            raise ValueError("Open value must be positive.")
        self._open = value


if __name__ == "__main__":
    f = Foo()
    assert 2.718 == f.open
    f.open = 3.14
    assert 3.14 == f.open
```

The key is that you want `self.open` to be a setter **method**,
so the (private) value belongs in a different object named `self._open`.

---

There's no conflict between these names and the popular builtin
[open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).
But as a rule of thumb,
it's typically a good idea to avoid such names.
We steer clear of shadowing and human confusion.